# Randomly selecting 7 cards out of a deck and distributing them

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a simple poker game as part of learning Python. My goal at this moment is to randomly select 9 cards out of a deck of 52, then spreading out the 9 cards for various purposes (two cards per player, three cards for the flop, and so on). Here is what I have come up with:

```
import itertools
import random

suits = ['S', 'C', 'D', 'H']
faces = ['A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'T', 'J', 'Q', 'K']

# get 9 random cards out of the deck:

random_cards = random.sample(set(itertools.product(faces, suits)),9)

# assign cards for later use during hand:

player_1_cards = [random_cards[0:2]]
player_2_cards = [random_cards[2:4]]
flop = [random_cards[4:7]]
turn = [random_cards[7]]
river = [random_cards[8]]
```

Please keep in mind that the cards will then be "put through" a function that will check what hand each player has (pair, set, straight, etc.)

I'm a complete beginner so was wondering if this is a good way to go about such a task in Python, or is there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: Seems reasonable enough. I would just generate the deck with a simple list comprehension and then sample from it in a separate line. Since this code works, it probably belongs at code review rather than here.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry for posting in the wrong place.

Comment: Don't worry about it. I'd much rather see readable code in the wrong place than unreadable code in the right place. Here is the link to code review: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  A final remark: you probably want `flop = random_cards[4:7]` rather than `flop = [random_cards[4:7]]`. A slice is already a list, do you really want a list inside a list?

Comment: You're right, thanks again.